# "No space left on device" but plenty of disk and inodes

Tags: server, hard-drive, disk-usage

I have an 8TB WD red disk, with 273gb available disk space, and plenty of inodes. But I cannot even create a directory.

```sh
user@server:/media/WD 8TB 2$ mkdir tmp
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘tmp’: No space left on device
```

I've been searching for answers, but unable to find anything useful.

It's a fresh Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS install. Though the content on the /media\WD 8TB x aren't new.

```sh
$ df -h -Bg
Filesystem                                    1G-blocks  Used Available Use% Mounted on
udev                                                 2G    0G        2G   0% /dev
tmpfs                                                1G    1G        1G   1% /run
/dev/sda2                                          146G   14G      125G  10% /
tmpfs                                                2G    0G        2G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs                                                1G    0G        1G   0% /run/lock
tmpfs                                                2G    0G        2G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/loop0                                           1G    1G        0G 100% /snap/core/7270
/dev/loop1                                           1G    1G        0G 100% /snap/core/8268
/dev/sdb1                                         7394G 7096G        0G 100% /media/WD 8TB 1
/dev/sdd1                                         7394G 7373G        0G 100% /media/WD 8TB 3
/dev/sdc1                                         7394G 7121G        0G 100% /media/WD 8TB 2
tmpfs                                                1G    0G        1G   0% /run/user/1000
/dev/sde1                                         1833G  349G     1392G  21% /media/WD Elements
```

```sh
$ df -i
Filesystem                                       Inodes  IUsed     IFree IUse% Mounted on
udev                                             491041    510    490531    1% /dev
tmpfs                                            498893    764    498129    1% /run
/dev/sda2                                       9773056 643326   9129730    7% /
tmpfs                                            498893      1    498892    1% /dev/shm
tmpfs                                            498893      3    498890    1% /run/lock
tmpfs                                            498893     18    498875    1% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/loop0                                        12823  12823         0  100% /snap/core/7270
/dev/loop1                                        12842  12842         0  100% /snap/core/8268
/dev/sdb1                                     244191232   9294 244181938    1% /media/WD 8TB 1
/dev/sdd1                                     244191232  19039 244172193    1% /media/WD 8TB 3
/dev/sdc1                                     244191232  15604 244175628    1% /media/WD 8TB 2
tmpfs                                            498893     11    498882    1% /run/user/1000
/dev/sde1                                     122093568   2150 122091418    1% /media/WD Elements
```

Comment: According to the output of `df -h` the partition "WD 8TB 2" is full.

Comment: Yes, `df -h -Bg` shows /dev/sdb1, /dev/sdc1, and /dev/sdd1 all show no space left,  although all three  of those have plenty of inodes as shown by `df -i `.. Only /dev/sda2 has space left.

Comment: The 1G-blocks column, what's that then? How come I can write 3737GB of data on `/dev/sdd1` but only 7121GB on `/dev/sdc1`? And also I can still write data to `/dev/sdb1` even though it's 100% full...